# How to set first page left in PDF?

Tags: pdf

For an assignment I need to create a dual page pdf, with two pages side by side.
Using Scribus (Linux, Debian) I can set the first page to be on the left in Scribus, but as soon as I export to pdf, and open in a document viewer, the first page will appear on the right.
Is there a way to force the first page to display on the left? Either through Scribus, or by altering the PDF once it has been exported?
I also have Windows ten on dual boot in case there is a windows only solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are always viewing the PDF with two pages displayed at the same time. If the first page is appearing on the right-hand side, I would check the preferences of the viewer to make sure nothing is set there that defines how the pages should be laid out when viewing two pages.

In the PDF though, there is a setting that might be useful here for you. In the *Viewer Preferences* dictionary that is in the **Document Catalog** there is a key/value pair that can be set for *Direction*. This should be set to either L2R (for left to right) or R2L (for right to left). This should default to L2R, it sounds like you may be running into a situation where it is either being ignored or set to R2L.

Comment: That setting is defined as "The predominant reading order for text: 
**L2R** Left to right 
**R2L** Right to left (including vertical writing systems, such as 
Chinese, Japanese, and Korean)". As far as I understand the question, this is not the setting he is looking for.

Comment: @mkl it sounds like it could be as they mention in the first line that they need to "create a dual page pdf, with two pages side by side" and that they "can set the first page to be on the left in Scribus". They then go on to ask "Is there a way to force the first page to display on the left?"

In the ISO specification for PDF it reads "This entry has no direct effect on the document’s contents or page numbering but may be used to determine the relative positioning of pages when displayed side by side or printed n-up. Default value: L2R."

Comment: I seriously do doubt you are right in your interpretation of the question but I have to admit it is a possible interpretation. Thus, the only one who can tell is the OP himself who unfortunately does not seem to care anymore.